how to loop over dataset and extract each value alone in PDF/EXCEL format in R
i have a dataset that contains column for ID and one for their URL to download, each ID has 2 URLS,
i want to download each two URLS and convert them to one PDF file named with their ID.
i want one PDF for each ID.
# demo dataset

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 Full_Path = c("https://test1.png","https://test1.png",
                               "https://test1.png","https://test1.png",
                               "https://test1.png","https://test1.png"))


for (url in df$Full_Path) {
 
download.file(url, destfile = basename(url), method="curl", extra="-k", mode="wb")

fl = list.files(full.names = T, pattern = '.png')

img = image_read(fl) # read from vector of paths

img2 = image_append(img, stack = TRUE) # places pics above one another

image_write(img2, format="pdf", file.path(dir,paste('IMG',today(),'.pdf'))) 

}

unlink(fl)


but after this loop all printed in one PDF, i want to have one pdf for each ID

I am not sure the code below answers the question.
The output file names have the number in their names.
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 Full_Path = c("https://test1.png","https://test1.png",
                               "https://test1.png","https://test1.png",
                               "https://test1.png","https://test1.png"))

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  url <- df$Full_Path[i]
  fl <- basename(url)
  download.file(url, destfile = fl, method="curl", extra="-k", mode="wb")
  img <- image_read(fl) # read from vector of paths
  img2 <- image_append(img, stack = TRUE) # places pics above one another
  
  # sprintf's format string outputs a string
  # with the formats replaced by
  #   %02d - an 2 digits integer padded with zeros
  #   %s   - a string, in this case the system date
  outfile <- sprintf('IMG_%02d_%s.pdf', i, today())
  outfile <- file.path(dir, outfile)
  image_write(img2, format = "pdf", outfile)
}

unlink(fl)


Edit
The code below creates a list of sub-data.frames by ID and processes each sub-df separately. It should write one file per ID with the contents of the downloaded image files.
library(magick)

sp <- split(df, df$ID)
lapply(sp, \(X) {
  i <- X$ID |> unique()
  # download and read all files, pipe to image_append
  # to combine them in one image only
  img <- sapply(X$Full_Path, \(url) {
    fl <- basename(url)
    download.file(url, destfile = fl, method="curl", extra="-k", mode="wb")
    image_read(fl)
    # clean up after reading, commented out
    # because it might be a good idea to keep
    # the files, it avoids having to read them
    # again if they are needed later
    # unlink(fl)
  }) |> image_append(stack = TRUE)
  #
  outfile <- sprintf('IMG_%02d_%s.pdf', i, Sys.Date())
  outfile <- file.path(dir, outfile)
  image_write(img, format = "pdf", outfile)
})
rm(sp)


thanks @Rui , it worked but printed each URL in PDF, i want both urls that related to the same id to be in one PDF

@HassanElleithy See if the edit solves the problem.

it worked with first ID download the two urls as .png then crashed and gave me this, Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object. –

@HassanElleithy It's difficult to say what is going on without the files. Can you add a print(class(img)) after the pipe?
